# how to add new class to existing project in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to Netbeans environment. I want to check the existing project code with different formulas. Each class have Jframes. if i right click the jframe and click refactor finally copy the file in another name. i get below message.
[image]

Please help me out this problem.

Comment: You were most likely using the NetBeans GUI editor (or GUI GUI editor if you will). Another file is created which contains the XML code to tell NetBeans what code to autogenerate - you need to copy this XML too.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly ,

go to your project then right click on `jframe class >> refactor >> copy`

then give a new name.then new class will be created and you can edit it from visual editor also.

1)

[image]

---

2)

[image]

3)

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much your reply. i did what u say. it works correctly

Comment: @user3264793 i'm happy .you can accept my answer if it's the answer